# Adjust RecyclerView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have ViewPgaer implemented like that:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And fragment implemented like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvNotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that RecyclerView now covers my tabs:

[image: Elem1 covers tabs]

My question is how I can position RecyclerView (and any other layout) to not cover tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a margin Top of around 50dp to your RecyclerView in the xml file. 
Also, adjust the margin Top value as per your need of the UI.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it automatically? Will it work on any device?

Comment: You can do it programmatically that in this case that doesnt seems to be needed. Just go with xml. Also, it will work for any device size and density. To confirm, in the preview tab, check your design over multiple devices and sizes.